# Themida Anti Dumping not working

Tags: .net

I am using Themida to protect my application and i enable Anti-Dumping option however any DLL embedded to my app can be easily dumped from the memory and totally unobfuscated so what should i do ?

Answer (score 3):

You should merge the assembly instead of embedding it. An embedded assembly is not recognized by Themida, but a merged assembly emits the relevant code you are using into the executable you are protecting. An application like Eazfuscator.NET (http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) has options to merge assemblies, and I am sure there are other solutions. Once merged, protect your executable as normal with Themida and your code will be safe(r).

Comment: Any suggestion of application to merge cause i can't use 2 obfuscators

Comment: What i am trying to do now is embed the dlls i want to obfuscate and merge the others however something is wrong and the application keeps asking for missing dlls for no reason.

Comment: I use EazFuscator as .NET obfuscator and to merge libraries into my main executable, then use Themida to make a native protected file from that. It works for me, look into EazFuscator a little more to see how to make it work for you :)